# ASIO - respone to a client request does not work

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

I have this piece of code on server

```
    void SocketTransportSession::DoRead() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket.async_read_some(ba::buffer(data),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
            if (!ec) {
                //TODO: process request
                socket.async_write_some(boost::asio::buffer(res, maxLen),
                    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                        assert(!ec);
                        assert(length == maxLen);
                        //read some more
                    DoRead();
                });
            }
        });
}
```

What I want basically is to read the client request (process it, a dummy for now) and reply to that, and repeat the cycle i.e. read some more from client/process/...

In the presented code asserts are not fired (we have confirmation that !ec and all replay was sent) but in my client code I don't see the response coming (i.e. client does a blocking read at that point and does not receive nothing).

**EDIT**
Just found that writing the server like this has expected behavior. It seems not to be evident the reason

```
void SocketTransportSession::DoRead() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket.async_read_some(ba::buffer(data),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
            if (!ec) {
                DoWrite(length);
            }
        });
}

void SocketTransportSession::DoWrite(std::size_t length) {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    ba::async_write(socket, ba::buffer(data),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
            if (!ec) {
                DoRead();
            }
    });
}
```

What happens here ?

Comment: How is the client blocking to receive data?

Comment: size_t reply_length = boost::asio::read(s,boost::asio::buffer(reply, max_length))

Comment: After your update, I suspect it has to do with the lifetime of the lambdas, though since they capture by copy, I can't put my finger on it.  For readability I'd probably do it the second time any way.

Comment: What are `data` and `res`? Aren't they local?

Comment: @IgorR. Of course not.